# Lookup table formula (trip planner)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-sheets

I want to be able to dynamically add a value from a lookup table depending on whether or not a value exists.

This seems like a question that should be solvable with some kind of 'lookup' command, but I can't figure it out.

I've made this a public worksheet anyone can see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10r7oxMEFU6tpJ32zxSuzk4bEtWyAnb7PGtzDxBy8gq4/edit?usp=sharing

There are four columns of names, but it only needs to work with one (clearly).

Let me be more specific. In the linked Google sheet, cell B31 is key.

Here's the user experience: If you put a value into a cell then that means you (assuming you're Joe) want to visit that location for X days (whatever value you input). But then let's say you put another value in a cell further down the list, so now you want to go from the first location to the second, and spend Y days at this new location. The formula in cell B31 should use the table of hours from the "Distances" tab and add that time to the total time that it's calculating.

In this way you can magically plan your trip. The value at the bottom of the column (B31) will be the day your trip needs to finish on to do all the things you want to do, including the travel time between the locations you chose.

Comment: Jeeped, if you care, Google Spreadsheet operates very similarly now to Excel, and is the reason why I included it in the tags. Look at my answer, it'll be very familiar to you.

Answer (score 0):

Went on a hike, realized I could use another column.

The answer is now on that public sheet, I created a new column for 'Joe' with the following formula which calculates the rolling new date.

```
 =G2+B3+IF(ISBLANK($B3),0,(INDEX(Distances!$B$2:$AD$30,MATCH(INDIRECT("Trip Planner!A"&(COUNTA(B$2:B3)+1)),Distances!$B$1:$AD$1,0),MATCH(INDIRECT("Trip Planner!A"&COUNTA(B$2:B3)),Distances!$A$2:$A$30,0)))/24)
```

Basically, the logic goes, take the previous time plus the time spent at this location... THEN (assuming the value at this location exists) use 2-column lookup (that is, an index with two match calls) to dynamically find the distance from the last visited location to this one... and add that distance to the mix.